# How to include styles in React create portal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom-events

I have ViewAllGraphs class:

```
import '../styles/Graph.css'
export class ViewAllGraphs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showWindowPortal: false,
}
```

And render method:

```
return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.showWindowPortal && (
                        <Graph closeWindowPortal={this.closeWindowPortal} >
                            <h1>Id графика : {this.state.currentId}</h1>
                            <h1>Название графика : {this.state.currentTitle}</h1>
                            <img o src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.currentImage}`} />
                            <h1>Данные графика : {this.state.currentData}</h1>
                            <button className="graph-button-close" onClick={() => this.closeWindowPortal()} >
                                Закрыть график
                        </button>
                        </Graph>
                    )
                }
</div>
```

My CSS file is located in `../styles/Graph.css`

I want to style my graph component, for example, the button. This is code of this component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import '../styles/Graph.css'

class Graph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: 0,
        }
        this.containerEl = null;
        this.externalWindow = null;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.externalWindow = window.open('', '');
        this.containerEl = this.externalWindow.document.createElement('div');
        this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
        this.externalWindow.document.title = 'A React portal window';
        this.externalWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            this.props.closeWindowPortal();
        });

        this.shouldComponentUpdate();
        this.setState({
            id: 1,
        })
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return true;
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.externalWindow.close();
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.containerEl) {
            return null;
        }
        else
            return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
    }
};

export default Graph
```

I am trying to include the CSS file and apply `className="graph-button-close"` in render method to my button, but it's not working. Why can't I import the CSS file to graph class?

Comment: Try `import './styles/Graph.css'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these code:

```
    this.containerEl = this.externalWindow.document.createElement('div');
    this.containerEl.className = 'image';
    this.containerEl.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150)';
    // add the image to its container; add both to the body
    // this.containerEl.appendChild(img);
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
```

Or for current elem you can use inline styles in parent component

```
let styleConfig = { backgroundColor: 'blue' }
```

In render method:

```
 <p style={styleConfig}>Данные графика : {this.state.currentData}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

To style a component functionally, and I hope this works for Class Components as well, is that for the styling part of the top of the file, I import the style as a component, something like this,

```js
import componentStyling from '../styles/Graphs.css`;
```

A bit of advice is that 99% of the time, I want a style to only apply to that component. It's tremendously hard to think of unique class names every single time I make to add styling to a component, so I rename my CSS files with the following format, `classComponentName.module.css`, or `classComponentName.module.scss`, if you're using SCSS.

So, whatever the name of the component you're making is, whether it's functional or a class component, name your CSS files with respect to that and then suffix it with `.module.css`.

Now, the import looks something like this,

```js
import componentStyling from `../styles/Graphs.module.css`;
```

Now, in the rendering part of the component, wherever I want to apply a class from `Graphs.module.css` to an HTML component in the component I have, I simply write,

```js
<htmlElement className={componentStyling.classNameFromTheStylesFile}>
{/* some more JSX here */}
</htmlElement>
```

Where `classNameFromTheStylesFile` is a class name that exists within `Graphs.module.css`, which can be for example,

```css
.classNameFromTheStylesFile {
    background-color: blue;
};
```

I hope I got the question right.

Cheers!